# result of incrementing a int variable varies, due to the presence or absence of System.out.println() statements

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to learn the concept of thread interference in java and have came up with the following code. I have noticed that when I run the code with `System.out.println("from t1: " + c1.value());` and `System.out.println("from t2: " + c1.value());`, the printed out result will always equal to 20000.

However, when I run the code without the `System.out.println()` statements, the result will always be 10000 < result < 20000. Why is this happening?

```
public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter c1 = new Counter();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    c1.increment();
                    System.out.println("from t1: " + c1.value());
                }
            }

        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    c1.increment();
                    System.out.println("from t2: " + c1.value());
                }
            }

        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println(c1.value());
    }

    private int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed in the past that adding System.out.print statement in the code can significantly slow down the code if it's in a loops/recursion. So I'm guessing that since the print statement are slowing down the execution, both threads have the time to do all the increments without interfering, and without the println(), not all increments register, so you get less than 20000. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print statements slow the threads down enough for the interference to be an issue. When the print statements are removed, your threads are able to get through all 10E4 iterations before they hand-off control. So, the time it takes the thread to iterate 10E4 times is too short. If you counted to 10E5 instead of 10E4 you would likely see the interference even in the absence of the print statements.

To illustrate, let `p` be a print statement and let `+` be an increment. Denote a thread start event by `S` and termination with `T`
With print statements you have something like:

```
t1:      S| +p+p+p+... |    idle   | +p+pT |
t2:           S|  idle |+p+p+p+... | idle  | +pT|
main:          |               idle             | p
```

Without print statements you have something like:

```
t1: S| ++++++ T|
t2:                  S| ++++++ T|
main:                 |  idle   |  p
```

Note: On my machine, I can iterate over a mere 5000 and see the interference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! now everything starts to make sense. :)